# Postgres 9.4.12 Slow queries

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.4

I'm having slow queries with my postgres in a table with 9 million rows.

Query: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT date_point, geo, alarms, status FROM  tracking_master WHERE id_asset = 151 AND date_point >= '2017-07-21 19:20:05' AND date_point <= '2017-07-21 19:25:05' ORDER BY date_point asc LIMIT 1000`

Here the query EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):

```
Limit  (cost=161175.31..161175.32 rows=1 width=579) (actual time=60734.109..60734.113 rows=5 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=23470 read=114350
  ->  Sort  (cost=161175.31..161175.32 rows=1 width=579) (actual time=60734.107..60734.110 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: date_point
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
        Buffers: shared hit=23470 read=114350
        ->  Index Scan using idx_tracking_master_id_asset on tracking_master  (cost=0.43..161175.30 rows=1 width=579) (actual time=80.682..60734.081 rows=5 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (id_asset = 151)
              Filter: ((date_point >= '2017-07-21 19:20:05-03'::timestamp with time zone) AND (date_point <= '2017-07-21 19:25:05-03'::timestamp with time zone))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 202512
              Buffers: shared hit=23470 read=114350
Planning time: 0.204 ms
Execution time: 60734.152 ms
```

Comment: What's the query you're trying to optimize? How are the tables defined? Indexes? We need more information to be able to know what could be improved (if anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the query, it's hard to help. It seems you have something like this in your where clause:

```
    id_asset=151 
AND (date_point >= '2017-07-21 19:20:05-03') 
AND (date_point <= '2017-07-21 19:25:05-03')
```

and have an index, on the id_asset column.

Try creating a multicolumn index, on `(id_asset, date_point)`. I see you are using an ORDER BY clause too. It might help to specify the sort order on the date column.

Example:

```
CREATE INDEX multicol_index ON tracking_master (id_asset, date_point DESC);
```

(Tip: use VACUUM ANALYZE after creating the index)

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer, just two remarks: 1) Why `DESC` on the index? 2) Good statistics are always necessary, but unless you create an index on an expression, it is not necessary to `ANALYZE`.

Comment: 1, why ASC? :) they can be equally good depending on the use case. What we don't know.
2, ANALYZE forces the DBMS to update the statistics (according to the docs). Also I VACUUM with ANALYZE from habit. It doesn't hurt.

Comment: "It doesn't hurt" depends on your system load. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You're right. I usually use this when the load is low, or somebody asks me to do.